# How To Run Google test from terminal on C code?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I am testing C code using googleTest.
My test.cpp file look like that

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
 

extern "C" {
#include "list.h"
#include "list.c"
}

TEST(ListTest, singleInsertion) {
// some tests
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

However trying to run the test from the terminal using
`g++ test.cpp   -lgtest` gives Errors and warning as if the code being tested is C++ not C.

Error and warning Examples :
`error: invalid conversion for mallocs`  and
`warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*'`

how can I declare that my tested files are C not C++ ?

Comment: strongly suggest: do not do: `#include "list.c"`  Rather, create a header file for `list.c`  Then correct your compile and link statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However trying to run the test from the terminal using `g++ test.cpp   -lgtest` gives Errors and warning as if the code being tested is C++ not C.

That's because you are compiling it as C++ by using the `g++` compiler.  Use `gcc` to compile as C.

Unfortunately, this code won't compile as C - it'll choke on the `google::InitGoogleTest()` call because C doesn't recognize the `::` scoping operator.  I'm not familiar with this testing framework, but at first glance it looks like it's meant to be used with C++, not C.

The way to fix this is to remove the `#include "list.c"` directive

```
extern "C" {
#include "list.h"
}
```

and compile it *separately* as C:

```
gcc -c list.c
```

then compile your tester:

```
g++ -c test.cpp
```

and then link the object files with the library:

```
g++ -o test test.o list.o -lgtest
```